# How do I create a Powershell Script to Output cmd-lets example files to txt file?

Tags: file, powershell

I asked this and came up with the answer on my own.  See the example below:

Answer (score -1):

```
$filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the Command you want examples for'
$pathloc = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the path of where the example files will be stored"

get-help $filename -Examples | Out-File ($pathloc + $filename + ".txt")
```